# Get the content of a function in js

Tags: javascript

I have a script which grabs all the scripts from a page. I do that like this:

```
scripts = $(this).contents().find('script');
```

Then i check if this script is text:

```
if( $(this).text() != '' )
```

And when it is I also need to check if this script has a function called init, so i do this

```
if (typeof $(this).init == 'function')
```

So far this works ok. My problem is i need to get the content of that init function.

I will also add that `$(this).text()` besides the init function, has a document.ready and another function.

And I just need the content of the init.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the function, and it looks like you do, then you simply call

```
var myFn = $(this).init.toString()
```

And you will get the function as a string. You can manipulate it to your liking and later evaluate the string with one of the following methods

- `new Function(myFn)()`
- `eval(myFn)`
- `(1, eval(myFn))`

If you need to call the function then from *within the called function* you can try with this:

```
arguments.callee.toString()
```

For example

```
console.log(arguments.callee.toString())
```

Note that working with arguments.callee [won't work in strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)

I hope that helps

Comment: I am sorry grgur but could you explain this a bit more?

Comment: I updated my answer to be more precise. Let me know if i can explain it any better

Comment: Well, I had tried that before, `var xpto = $(this).init.toString();`, but when i output that `console.log(xpto);` i get this : **function (a,b,c){var e,f;if(!a)return this;if(c=c||A,"string"==typeof a){if(e="<"===a[0]&&">"===a[a.length-1]&&a.length>=3?[null,a,null]:B.exec(a),!e||!e[1]&&b)return!b||b.jquery?(b||c).find(a):this.constructor(b).find(a);if(e[1]){if(b=b instanceof n?b[0]:b,n.merge(this,n.parseHTML(e[1],b&&b.nodeType?b.ownerDocument||b:d,!0)),x.test(e[1])&&n.isPlainObject(b))for(e in b)n.isFunction(this[e])?this[e](b[e]):this.attr(e,b[e]);return this}return f=d.getElementById(...**

Answer (score 0):

any function:

```
var foo = function() {
   console.log('a')
}
```

can be converted to the string representation like this:

```
var functionString = foo.toString();
```

And back to javascript:

```
var functionAgain = eval("(" + functionString + ")");
functionAgain()
```